# Sphinx documentation: how to reference a Python property?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

How can I reference a method, decorated with `@property`?

For simple methods, `:py:meth:` is working fine, but not for properties: it does not create a link to them.

Comment: What about using `:py:attr:` with the property?

Comment: I tried `:py:attr:` too. Nothing changed: the link does not appear.

Comment: Are you using `functools.wraps` to retain the wrapped function's documentation? Could you provide an example of what you're doing, and the expected and actual output?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use `:py:attr:` instead. This example works fine for me:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    """This is the docstring of SomeClass."""

    @property
    def some_property(self):
        """This is the docstring of some_property"""
        return None

    def some_method(self):
        """This is the docstring of some_method.

        And this is a reference to :py:attr:`~some_property`
        """
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. It renders `MyClass.my_prop` with the proper link.

```
:attr:`.MyClass.my_prop`
```

This renders just `my_prop`, with the same link.

```
:attr:`~.MyClass.my_prop`
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `:py:obj:` instead.

`:py:attr:` won't work for me when the property is in another page.